# Issue with Trials() when using Hyperopt?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperopt

I am attempting to use Hyperopt for the first time for hyperparameter tuning in Python. I have read through the documentation and want to try this on an XgBoost classifier. "X_train" and "y_train" is the data frame after splitting it into testing and training sets. Here is my code so far:

```
#Hyperopt Parameter Tuning
from hyperopt import hp, STATUS_OK, Trials, fmin, tpe
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


def objective(space):
  print(space)
  clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective = space[objective],
                     max_depth = int(space[max_depth]),
                     learning_rate = space[learning_rate],
                     n_estimators = space[n_estimators])


  #eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (Xcv, Ycv)]
  clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric='auc',
         early_stopping_rounds=10, verbose=False)

  #pred = clf.predict(X_test)
  auc = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
  return{'auc':auc, 'status': STATUS_OK }




space = {'booster': 'gbtree',
         'objective': 'binary:logistic',
         'eval': 'auc',
         'max_depth': hp.quniform('max_depth', 1, 100, 5),
         'learning_rate': hp.loguniform('learning_rate', 0.2, 0.3),
         'n_estimators': hp.quniform('n_esimators', 5, 500, 10)}


trials = Trials()
best = fmin(fn=objective,
            space=space,
            algo=tpe.suggest,
            max_evals=3, # change
            trials=trials)

print(best)
```

I am getting the following error which highlights "trails=trails":

```
TypeError: ap_loguniform_sampler() got multiple values for argument 'size'
```

I have done some research and haven't been able to find a solution to this error. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

According to document, hp.loguniform can take only 3 arguments as below.

```
hp.loguniform(label, low, high)
```

This could be the reason for the error. Kindly check.

Comment: Thanks for response. Tried this, new failure message is: KeyError: <function objective at 0x7efc85079400> and it highlights the same part of the code. I edited with the changes above in description.

Comment: @rmahesh did you get any resolution for the said question?